# How does the PIN work in the RSA SecurID phone app?

Tags: rsa, multi-factor

I use the RSA SecurID phone app to connect to the VPN at my work. I run the app and type a 4 to 8 digit PIN. Then the app gives me a 6 digit code to connect to the VPN. Does the PIN change the result? What if I type the wrong PIN?

Answer (score 1):

The phone app has an algorithm to generate a new 6 digit random number every 60 seconds. Your PIN is simply added to that number *without carry*.  If you want to see the random number, just enter nothing for the PIN (or all zeros).

For example if the random number is 334455 and your PIN is 781923, then the resulting code will be 015378.

because

```
3 + 7 = 0  (throw away the carry)
3 + 8 = 1  (throw away the carry)
4 + 1 = 5
4 + 9 = 3  (throw away the carry)
5 + 2 = 7
5 + 3 = 8
```

I don't see how this information would be ever useful, but it seemed interesting.